# Filtering a Magento 2 Object Repository

Tags: magento2, api, filter, repository, search-criteria

In Magento 2, can you use a product repository to filter by product attributes?

In Magento 2, you can use a search criteria object

```
\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria,
```

and a repository

```
\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
```

To fetch a list of objects

```
$searchCriteria->getPageSize(10);
$list = $productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
```

However, the searchCriteria object doesn't (seem to?) have direct filtering capabilities.  The search criteria class **does** have methods for adding something called filterGroups

```
#File: lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Api/SearchCriteria.php        

public function getFilterGroups()
{
    $filterGroups = $this->_get(self::FILTER_GROUPS);
    return is_array($filterGroups) ? $filterGroups : [];
}

public function setFilterGroups(array $filterGroups = null)
{
    return $this->setData(self::FILTER_GROUPS, $filterGroups);
}
```

But it's not clear what, exactly, a filter group is thanks to PHP's untyped arrays.

How can I use a Magento 2 repository to do things like

> - Show me all the products with [this specific SKU]
> - Show me all the products created after [this date]
> - etc.

Comment: It seems that said groups is an array of Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup , which in turn has \Magento\Framework\Api\Filter filters, filters can be built with \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder and condition_type is in the form of 'eq', 'neq', 'gt' etc. But couldn't find list of supported condition types :\

Comment: Actually, something like a list can be found at Magento/Framework/Api/CriteriaInterface.php:79

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Check out the following sample class. To filter by SKU, try this:

```
$productFilterDemo->getProducts('sku', 'product_sku_value', 'eq');
```

To get products created after specific date, this:

```
$productFilterDemo->getProducts('created_at', 'creation date', 'gt');
```

Sample class:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModlueName\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class ProductFilterDemo
{
    /** @var ProductRepositoryInterface */
    protected $productRepository;

    /** @var SearchCriteriaBuilder */
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * Get products with filter.
     * 
     * @param string $fieldName
     * @param string $fieldValue
     * @param string $filterType
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface[]
     */
    public function getProducts($fieldName, $fieldValue, $filterType)
    {
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter($fieldName, $fieldValue, $filterType)->create();
        $products = $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
        return $products->getItems();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was after!  It looks like adding multiple filters creates "OR" conditions — is there a way to create "AND" conditions?

Comment: — if you have a moment.  Am I using filter group correctly?  They seem to be applying as an OR, not an AND http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91023/magento-2-product-repositories-filter-groups-and-and

Comment: Filters are combined with "OR" inside one filter group, and each group is combined with "AND" on level of search criteria. Take a look at: \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder::setFilterGroups($groups[]) and \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder::setFilters($filters[])

Comment: I am using Magento 2.3, Search criteria builder does not filter the item if an item is "out_of_stock"?

Answer (score 17):

```
public function __construct(
    ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
    FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
}

public function getProducts()
{
    $filters[] = $this->filterBuilder
        ->setField('sku')
        ->setConditionType('eq')
        ->setValue('something')
        ->create();
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilters($filters);

    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
    $searchResults = $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
    return $searchResults->getItems();
}
```

Comment: Looks like in your example `\Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder` is used (search-specific one), while I used `\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder` (generic for all services), see my answer. Also it provides simpler way of adding filter, `addFilter()` signatures are different.

Comment: Agreed, it's a slightly different solution.

Comment: can addfilter use only 1 param?

Comment: @LDusan, Can you please tell me how can i use "$searchCriteriaBuilder,"  in objectmanager ?

Comment: I think that you should add it in the constructor of your class, why would you want to use the object manager for that?