# Magento 2: Product Repositories, Filter Groups, and `AND`

Tags: php, magento2, api, search-criteria, repository

I'm trying to use a product repository to fetch a list of products.  I want to fetch based on two filters, combined with an `AND` criteria, but things don't seem to be working.  Do I not understand how filter groups work?  Or is this a bug that should be reported?

Specifically, (silly example for simplicity's sake) I have a constructor where I inject a filter builder, filter group builder, and a search criteria builder

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder $filterGroupBuilder 
)
{
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    $this->filterBuilder         = $filterBuilder;
    $this->filterGroupBuilder    = $filterGroupBuilder;
}
```

Then, later on in a method, I use the filter builders to build two filters

```
    $filter1 = $this->filterBuilder->setField('sku')
            ->setValue('24-MB01')
            ->setConditionType('eq')
            ->create();

    $filter2 = $this->filterBuilder->setField('sku')
            ->setValue('WT08-XS-Black')
            ->setConditionType('eq')
            ->create();
```

Then I use the filter group builder to build a filter group that consists of these two filters

```
    $filter_group = $this->filterGroupBuilder
        ->addFilter($filter1)
        ->addFilter($filter2)
        ->create();
```

Then I used a search criteria builder, set the filter group on it

```
    $criteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
        ->setFilterGroups([$filter_group])
        ->setPageSize(100)
        ->create();            
    return $criteria
```

Finally, when I use this criteria with a product repository (used elsewhere, leaving out constructor and di to avoid confusion)

```
/* @var Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface */
$list = $productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
```

The call is succesfull **but** I get back two products.  i.e. the SKU filter was applied as a `OR`, not an `AND`. I'd expect this query to return nothing.

If I dig into the `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepository` class, and take a look at the collection's select statment

```
protected function addFilterGroupToCollection(
    \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup $filterGroup,
    Collection $collection
) {
    //...
    if ($fields) {
        $collection->addFieldToFilter($fields);
    }

    //printf lives in my heart forever
    echo($collection->getSelect()->__toString());
    exit;
}
```

I see the criteria added with an `OR`

```
SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) AS `status`, IF(at_visibility.value_id > 0, at_visibility.value, at_visibility_default.value) AS `visibility` 

FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` 

INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status_default` ON (`at_status_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status_default`.`attribute_id` = '94') AND `at_status_default`.`store_id` = 0 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '94') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 1) 

INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility_default` ON (`at_visibility_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility_default`.`attribute_id` = '96') AND `at_visibility_default`.`store_id` = 0 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility` ON (`at_visibility`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility`.`attribute_id` = '96') AND (`at_visibility`.`store_id` = 1)

WHERE ((`e`.`sku` = '24-MB01') OR (`e`.`sku` = 'WT08-XS-Black'))
```

Is this a bug?  Is there a way (short of relying directly on the product collections and ditching the repositories) to make this work?

Comment: I have not looked into this area personally yet, but http://cyrillschumacher.com/2015/01/02/magento2---search-parameters-for-the-rest-api/ might be useful.

Comment: Real time Product example with OR conditions, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/apply-or-conditions-to-searchcriteria-filter-magento-2/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actual annotation of `\Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup` says (class phpDoc):

> Groups two or more filters together using a logical OR

It means that you need to create two groups with one filter in each.

Comment: Thanks for claring this up. You just got to love all the layers of abstraction in Magento 2 :-P

Comment: A clear explanation can be found at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/searching-with-repositories.html#filter-group

Answer (score 2):

In Magento 2 all the filters in same `FilterGroup` will be added using `OR` operator. But all the `FilterGroup` will be added using `AND` operator. So you will need to add multiple `FilterGroup`s as below:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$searchCriteria = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria');
$filter = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Api\Filter');
$filter->setField('category_id');
$filter->setValue(array(1, 2, 3));
$filter->setConditionType('in');

$filterGroup = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup');
$filterGroup->setFilters([$filter]);

$filterEnabled = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Api\Filter');
$filterEnabled->setField('status');
$filterEnabled->setValue(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
$filterEnabled->setConditionType('eq');

$filterGroupEnabled = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup');
$filterGroupEnabled->setFilters([$filterEnabled]);


$searchCriteria->setFilterGroups([$filterGroup, $filterGroupEnabled]);
```

In further details and logical combinations about search criteria, you can find at [Magento-2 Search Criteria](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/webapi/search-criteria.html)

Comment: This is incorrect.  The logic is implemented on a per Repository basis.

Comment: Hi @Alan Storm, this is tested solution. I have tested it for default store in Magento 2.1.0. Do you have any justification to declare it wrong, sir?

Comment: @karnalsingh This bug: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4287

Comment: @Alan Storm, that's what I have mentioned in my answer. All the Filter Groups are joined using AND operator and All the Filters in single Filter Group are joined using OR operator as per Magento 2 search criteria documentation. I have mentioned that this solution is tested with default store. What makes this answer wrong as per your comment, I did not get it.

Comment: @KamelSingh Did you read the bug report I linked?  Regardless of their intended behavior, the behavior of filters and filter groups is ultimately dependent on the behavior of the repository they're in.