# Magento2: How to add multiple AND and OR conditions to filter/filterGroups?

Tags: magento2, search-criteria

The question is too close to this topic:
[Magento 2: Product Repositories, Filter Groups, and `AND`](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91023/magento-2-product-repositories-filter-groups-and-and)

but is it possible to create criteria with multiple **OR** and **AND**?

In my case i would like to create alternative to this code:

```
/** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('special_from_date');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('special_to_date');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('special_price');
        $collection->setVisibility($this->catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

        $collection->addStoreFilter()->addAttributeToFilter(
            'special_from_date',
            [
                'or' => [
                    0 => ['date' => true, 'to' => $todayEndOfDayDate],
                    1 => ['is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('null')],
                ]
            ],
            'left'
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            'special_from_date',
            [
                'or' => [
                    0 => ['date' => true, 'from' => $todayStartOfDayDate],
                    1 => ['is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('null')],
                ]
            ],
            'left'
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            [
                ['attribute' => 'special_from_date', 'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')],
                ['attribute' => 'special_to_date', 'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')],
            ]
        )->addAttributeToSort(
            'special_from_date',
            'desc'
        );
```

The problem is that i have here several wrapped **OR** conditions and all of them  are combined using AND.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes it is possible

You can create an

```
\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
\Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
\Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder $filterGroupBuilder
```

After that define your filters

```
// AND
$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('attribute1','value2');
$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('attribute2','value2');

// OR
$attr3 = $this->filterBuilder->setField('attribute3')
            ->setValue('value3')
            ->setConditionType('eq')
            ->create();
$attr4 = $this->filterBuilder->setField('attribute4')
            ->setValue('value4')
            ->setConditionType('eq')
            ->create();

 $filterOr = $this->filterGroupBuilder
            ->addFilter($attr3)
            ->addFilter($attr4)
            ->create();
 $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setFilterGroups([$filterOr]);

 $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();

 $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
```

**GET ==>**

```
attribute1 = 'value1' AND attribute2 = 'value2' AND (attribute3='value3' OR attribute4 = 'value4')
```

Tell me if you have any other questions

```
    $attr1 = $this->filterBuilder->setField('attribute1')
        ->setValue('value1')
        ->setConditionType('eq')
        ->create();
    $attr2 = $this->filterBuilder->setField('attribute2')
        ->setValue('value2')
        ->setConditionType('eq')
        ->create();

    $filterOr1 = $this->filterGroupBuilder
        ->addFilter($attr1)
        ->addFilter($attr2)
        ->create();


    $attr3 = $this->filterBuilder->setField('attribute3')
        ->setValue('value3')
        ->setConditionType('eq')
        ->create();
    $attr4 = $this->filterBuilder->setField('attribute4')
        ->setValue('value4')
        ->setConditionType('eq')
        ->create();

    $filterOr2 = $this->filterGroupBuilder
        ->addFilter($attr3)
        ->addFilter($attr4)
        ->create();

    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setFilterGroups([$filterOr, $filterOr2]);

    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();

    $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
```

**GET ==>**

```
(attribute1 = 'value1' OR attribute2 = 'value2') AND (attribute3='value3' OR attribute4 = 'value4')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This criteria says: ```attribute1 = 'value2' AND  attribute2 = 'value2' AND (attribute3='value3' OR attribute4 = 'value4')```. I'm talking about this case:
 ```(attribute1 = 'value2' OR  attribute2 = 'value2') AND (attribute3='value3' OR attribute4 = 'value4')``` And more interesting staff is to use OR after this statement as well.

Comment: I update my answer you cant find the solution

Comment: @MohamedElMrabet Thanks for above code snippet. I want (attribute = 'value1') OR (attribute = 'value2' AND attribute = 'value3') OR (attribute = 'value3' AND attribute = 'value4') but i'm not able to achieve this. Can you please help?

Comment: @chiragdodia did you find any solutions? I also want (A AND B) OR (C AND D). If anyone else can help. Please let me know.

Comment: No, I haven't find the solution.

Comment: What approach you have used?

Comment: You cant do this simply, you must use AdvancedFilterProcessor in your repository

Comment: When multiple filters are used like this, is there a direct way to set priority for each filter? For example filter ```LIKE 'SearchText%'``` gets more priority, ```LIKE '%SearchText%'``` gets less priority, in a way such that matches for first filter come first in resulting collection.

Answer (score 3):

Magento applies the OR operator within the filters in the filter group, while the AND operator for joining the filter groups. This makes conditions like `(A and B) or (C and D)` tricky to implement. This is where the [distributive laws](https://www.mathreference.org/index/page/id/320/lg/en) of logical operators come in handy, because you can transform your conditions into a different set of conditions that can work with Magento's logic:

`(A and B) or (C and D) = (A or (C and D)) and (B or (C and D)) = (A or C) and (A or D) and (B or C) and (B or D)`

If this is too complicated for the desired purpose, one might also look into the [\Magento\Framework\Api\CombinedFilterGroup](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/7b3ae93dad62360d4ba93a1984075859f04288c2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Api/CombinedFilterGroup.php) class that lets you create filter groups that can group two or more filters together using 'OR' or 'AND' strategy.

Answer (score 0):

```
                      `->addAttributeToFilter([
                             ['attribute' => 'small_image','null' => true ],
                             ['attribute' => 'small_image','eq' => 'no_selection' ]
                        ]);`
```

Reads if attribute 'small_image' is null or attribute 'small_image' == 'no_selection';