# Magento 2: How to add OR condition b/w 2 AND conditions in Searchcriteria

Tags: magento2, search, search-criteria

I have a requirement where I found the list of specific orders according to the filtered conditions. I need to create a searchCriteria which I can pass to **$this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria)**. To pass searchcriteria, I need below condition:

> (status = 'pending' AND custom_field = 1) OR (status = 'review' AND
>   custom_field = 4)

I found multiple similar questions which answer about the combinations of conditions:

```
(attribute-A OR attribute-B) AND (attribute-C OR attribute-D)
```

[This](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/200945/45332) link will explain more what I want.
If anyone can help me please let me know.

Comment: please explain briefly

Comment: Please check I have added more explanation and added link through which it will be more easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can use Filter Group for this. Hope this will be useful.

```
Class YourClass
{
    protected $filterBuilder;
    protected $filterGroupBuilder;
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    protected $orderRepository;

    public function __construct(
        .....
        \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder $filterGroupBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository $orderRepository,
        .....
    ) {

        $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
        $this->filterGroupBuilder = $filterGroupBuilder;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    }

    public function yourFunction() {
        $filterA1 = $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('status')
            ->setConditionType('ed')
            ->setValue('pending')
            ->create();

        $filterA2 = $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('custom_field')
            ->setConditionType('eq')
            ->setValue('1')
            ->create();

        $filterGroup1 = $this->filterGroupBuilder
            ->addFilter($filterA1)
            ->addFilter($filterA2)
            ->create();

        $filterB1 = $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('status')
            ->setConditionType('ed')
            ->setValue('review')
            ->create();

        $filterB2 = $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('custom_field')
            ->setConditionType('eq')
            ->setValue('4')
            ->create();

        $filterGroup2 = $this->filterGroupBuilder
            ->addFilter($filterA1)
            ->addFilter($filterA2)
            ->create();


        // add filter group to setFilterGroups()
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
            ->setFilterGroups([$filterGroup1, $filterGroup2])
            ->create();

        $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);

    }
}
```

Ref: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/searching-with-repositories.html

Comment: This will create a condition: (status = 'pending' OR custom_field = 1) AND (status = 'review' OR custom_field = 4). I don't want this. Please check if you can provide the correct solution.