# Magento2 - Product Collection with custom condition

Tags: product, magento2, module

What is the best practice for adding custom condition of following collection?

1. Category view detail page **product collection**
2. Search page **product collection**

Give me some advice for that. How can I add condition with magento 2 default collection functionality.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Alex Paliarush please give some advice for this issue.

Comment: @KAndy please give some advice for this issue.

Comment: Check blog, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/apply-custom-conditions-for-product-collection-in-magento-2/

Comment: @SohelRana Can you please help me here? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/295095/68281

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In custom module product collection should not be used directly, because it is not part of public API and in case of future changes in core, this module may be broken. Instead, use `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::getList` with properly configured search criteria (`\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface`). 
See how to use product list with search criteria in [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/90968/697).