# How to get list of pages in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom, menu, page

How can I retrieve a list of available pages such as Contact Us, About Us, Home etc... in Magento 2, my purpose to get a list of pages is to build a custom menu on left side bar.
Also is there any way to build a custom menu for selected pages in Magento 2?

Comment: In Helper
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
 protected $_cmsPages;
 public function __construct(\Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Page\Collection $cmsPages) {
  $this->_cmsPages = $cmsPages;
 }
 public function getCMSPages(){
  return $this->_cmsPages;
 }
}
In phtml template file
<?php
 foreach($this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data')->getCMSPages() as $cms_page) {
  echo $cms_page->getTitle()."<br/>";
 }
?>

Answer (score 6):

For your information, even though the answers posted look like valid answer, it is recommended to use service contracts in Magento 2.

In your case a valid code would be to first inject the right service contract class in your constructor:

```
protected $_pageRepositoryInterface;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface $pageRepositoryInterface
) {
    $this->_pageRepositoryInterface = $pageRepositoryInterface;
    ...
}
```

Then you can do:

```
$this->_pageRepositoryInterface->getList($searchCriteria);
```

Where `$searchCriteria` is an instance of `\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface`

Comment: As far as I can see the getList method returns an array of data, not a page object with its ID right?

Comment: Yep, that data array returned by PageRepository bizarrely does not include the object id itself...

Comment: @koosa I updated my answer because the service contract class was wrong. You should be able to call `getItems` on the result of the `getList()` method

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism I am trying to do a similar thing with blocks however it is returning an array of arrays instead of an array of objects when I use `Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface`. Using M2.1.1.

Comment: @Raj try to call `getItems()` on the return result

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism yup, that's what method I am using: [link](http://f.chev.li/m2blocks.jpg). It appears that  `$this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray()` method does not return objects. I'll be happy to post most of the source as a new question.

Comment: @Raj, I am also getting array instead of object, did you manage to get an object? plus where can i find the url key to the cms pages.

Answer (score 3):

you can get it from object Manager

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $collection = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Page\CollectionFactory')->create();
// add Filter if you want 
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('is_active' , \Magento\Cms\Model\Page::STATUS_ENABLED);
    $pages = array('default' => '(Default) Customer Login Page');
    foreach($collection as $page){
       $pages[$page->getId()] = $page->getTitle();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This code will fetch you all enabled CMS pages:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface $pageRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
) {
    $this->_cmsPage = $pageRepository;
    $this->_search = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
}

public function toOptionArray()
{
    $pages = [];
    foreach($this->_cmsPage->getList($this->_getSearchCriteria())->getItems() as $page) {
        $pages[] = [
            'value' => $page->getIdentifier(),
            'label' => $page->getTitle()
        ];
    }
    return $pages;
}

protected function _getSearchCriteria()
{
    return $this->_search->addFilter('is_active', '1')->create();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is example :

```
#File: app/code/Pulsestorm/TutorialInstanceObjects/Command/Testbed.php

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory $pageFactory = 
)
{
    $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    return parent::__construct();
}
//...
public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $page = $this->pageFactory->create();
    foreach($page->getCollection() as $item)
    {
        $output->writeln($item->getId() . '::' . $item->getTitle());
    }

    $page = $this->pageFactory->create()->load(1);        
    var_dump($page->getData());
}
```

[For more see here.](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_instance_objects)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I got it working with help of your example and few customization to my code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method getList() from vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/PageRepository.php class.

You have to pass a SearchCriteria Object, here there is some example of its usage: [Filtering a Magento 2 Object Repository](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90966/filtering-a-magento-2-object-repository)

So pass PageRepository in the constructor of your block or create object with ObjectManager or pass it with registry from a controller and make a try.

I haven't try this solution, but it should be work.